# Can't send password via type="password"

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code, my problem is I can't send a post request if I use an input type="password". Here's my html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="login()">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my Angular controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('loginController',function($scope,$sanitize,$location,Authenticate){
    $scope.login = function(){
        Authenticate.save({
            'email': $sanitize($scope.email),
            'password': $sanitize($scope.password)
        },function() {
            $scope.flash = ''
            $location.path('/pos');
        },function(response){
            $scope.flash = response.data.flash
        })
    }
 })
```

My server-side php (Laravel):

```
public function store()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email' =>  Input::get('email'),
        'password' =>  Input::get('password'));

    return Response::json(  $credentials );
}
```

My post request on Firefox:

```
{"email":"admin@gmail.com","password":""}
```

and on Chrome:

```
  email: ""
password: ""
```

but if I remove `type="password"` it can pass the correct data on firefox :/ Is there something wrong on my html/JavaScript? My problem here is on posting/sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't named the input. Try this: `<input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>`

Comment: I see now that you also have the same problem with your email input. Name it and everything should work.

Comment: thank you @jonlink for your thoughts :) yeah I was thinking the same, I think its an angular problem.

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel , inside your User Model , `password` and `remember_token` are default declared as hidden fields , so it can not displayed in response :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

}
```